# Exporting Group Types from Azure AD Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I am trying to export all Azure AD groups, their owners, description, email and its group type. Such as Office 365, Security or Distrubution. I have managed to export everything correctly into a .csv except the group type. Get-AzureADGroup will return only "Group" and I can't get any results from get-msolgroup -grouptype.

Script I have been using:

```
$array = @()
$Properties=@{}
$Properties.add("GroupDisplayName","1")
$Properties.add("OwnerObjectId","2")
$Properties.add("OwnerObjectType","3")
$Properties.add("OwnerUserType","4")
$Properties.add("OwnerUserPrincipalName","5")
$Properties.add("GroupDescription","6")
$Properties.add("Email","7")
$Properties.add("GroupTypes","8")
$groups = Get-AzureADGroup -All $true
$GroupType = Get-MsolGroup -Grouptype
Foreach($group in $groups){

     $Owners = Get-AzureADGroupOwner -ObjectId $group.ObjectId -All $true
     $Properties.GroupDisplayName=$group.DisplayName
     $Properties.GroupDescription=$group.description
     $Properties.Email=$group.mail
     $Properties.GroupTypes=$group.GroupType
     if($Owners -ne $null){
       # group has owner
        Foreach($Owner in $Owners){ 
                $Properties.OwnerObjectId=$Owner.ObjectId
                $Properties.OwnerObjectType=$Owner.ObjectType
                $Properties.OwnerUserType=$Owner.UserType
                $Properties.OwnerUserPrincipalName=$Owner.UserPrincipalName
                $obj=New-Object PSObject -Property $Properties
                $array +=$obj 


        }
     }
     else{
                #group has no owner
                $Properties.OwnerObjectId=$null
                $Properties.OwnerObjectType=$null
                $Properties.OwnerUserType=$null
                $Properties.OwnerUserPrincipalName=$null
                $obj=New-Object PSObject -Property $Properties
                $array +=$obj  



     }

}
$array | export-csv -Path C:\scripts\Owners13.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, the command `Get-MsolGroup` is a command of Azure AD V1 module : [MSOnline](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/?view=azureadps-1.0). But the other commands you use are the command of Azure AD V2 module: [AzureAD](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/overview?view=azureadps-2.0). They are in different modules. So if you want to use the command `Get-MsolGroup`, you need to run the command `Connect-MsolService` at frist.
For example:

```
Connect-MsolService
Get-MsolGroup -all | Select-Object DisplayName, GroupType
```

[image]

Besides, if you just want to use AzureAD module to get group type, we can use the command `Get-AzureADMSGroup` to get it. But if we use the command, we need to make some judgments by the response's properties. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/groups-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0)
For example

```
Connect-AzureAD
Get-AzureADMSGroup -All $true | Select-Object DisplayName, GroupTypes,MailEnabled, SecurityEnabled
```

---

### Update

You can use the following script to implement your need.

```
connect-AzureAD
$array = @()
$Properties=@{}
$Properties.add("GroupDisplayName","1")
$Properties.add("OwnerObjectId","2")
$Properties.add("OwnerObjectType","3")
$Properties.add("OwnerUserType","4")
$Properties.add("OwnerUserPrincipalName","5")
$Properties.add("GroupDescription","6")
$Properties.add("Email","7")
$Properties.add("GroupTypes","8")
$groups = Get-AzureADGroup -All $true

Foreach($group in $groups){

     $Owners = Get-AzureADGroupOwner -ObjectId $group.ObjectId -All $true
     $Properties.GroupDisplayName=$group.DisplayName
     $Properties.GroupDescription=$group.description
     $Properties.Email=$group.mail
    
     $result=Get-AzureADMSGroup -Id $group.ObjectId | Select-Object GroupTypes,MailEnabled, SecurityEnabled, DisplayName

     If($result.GroupTypes -contains "Unified"){

            $Properties.GroupTypes="O365"

       }
       elseif($result.SecurityEnabled  ){
    
            $Properties.GroupTypes="Security"  
       }
       else{
           $Properties.GroupTypes="Distrubution"

       }
     
     if($Owners -ne $null){
       # group has owner
        Foreach($Owner in $Owners){ 
                $Properties.OwnerObjectId=$Owner.ObjectId
                $Properties.OwnerObjectType=$Owner.ObjectType
                $Properties.OwnerUserType=$Owner.UserType
                $Properties.OwnerUserPrincipalName=$Owner.UserPrincipalName
                $obj=New-Object PSObject -Property $Properties
                $array +=$obj 


        }
     }
     else{
                #group has no owner
                $Properties.OwnerObjectId=$null
                $Properties.OwnerObjectType=$null
                $Properties.OwnerUserType=$null
                $Properties.OwnerUserPrincipalName=$null
                $obj=New-Object PSObject -Property $Properties
                $array +=$obj  



     }

     
     

}
$array | export-csv -Path E:\test.csv -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation
```

[image]

Comment: I don't mind which module I use. I just need to be able to get the group types as well as all the other properties specified. How would I be able to implement the above script into mine?

Comment: Another possible GroupType is "DynamicMembership". This script will show an Azure DynamicMembership group as disctribution list